# Correct use of Lay or Laid in english sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

Which of the below sentences in the past tense is correct ?

The sentence **a** is from a song that I've heard.

> a) last night I lay in bed so blue.

> b) last night I laid in bed so blue

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is

> a) last night i lay in bed so blue.

"Lay" is the past tense of the intransitive "lie". I lie (present) I will lie (future) I lay (simple past) I had lain (past perfect). *I want to lie on the bed. Last night I lay on the bed.*

Also, confusingly, there is the transitive verb "lay". I lay (present) I will lay (future) I laid (simple past) I had laid (past perfect). *I want to lay the blanket on the bed. Last night I laid the blanket on the bed* - It is possible to say in the present "I lay me (or myself) down" but this is unusual and old-fashioned.

Native speakers often get these wrong when using Standard English, and also local dialects sometimes use non-standard forms.

[Lay, Lie, Lied, Lain: When Do We Use Which? (Britannica)](https://www.britannica.com/story/lay-lie-lied-lain-when-do-we-use-which)